# Why does my MSI prompt for administrator rights?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm trying get our MSI working for non-admin users.

I'm using `WixUI_Advanced`, but I'm still getting an admin prompt even when I select "Install just for you":

[image: installation scope dialog]

Looking at the MSI logs I can see that elevation is required, but I don't know why:

```
MSI (s) (68:54) [10:45:25:359]: Product not registered: beginning first-time install
MSI (s) (68:54) [10:45:25:359]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Deleting ALLUSERS property. Its current value is '1'.
MSI (s) (68:54) [10:45:25:359]: Product {32799511-D146-40F4-ACA7-5A76E6E38854} is not managed.
MSI (s) (68:54) [10:45:25:359]: Machine policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
MSI (s) (68:54) [10:45:25:359]: User policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
MSI (s) (68:54) [10:45:25:359]: MSI_LUA: Elevation required to install product, will prompt for credentials
```

Any idea why I'm getting prompted for admin rights?

---

**Edit**

I created an empty Wix project, used the `WixUI_Advanced` UI, and I'm getting the same issue :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ***Admin Rights Prompt***: In the WiX sample below, elevation will be requested and required for **per-machine** installation, but not for **per-user** installation.

---

***Heads-Up***: I personally do not like per-user setups. I find them to be borderline anti-patterns in my subjective opinion. It relates to poor serviceability (upgrades, patching, etc...) and a number of other details such as dubious folder redirects and some other "high-astonishment" factors. There are also a number of restrictions summarized nicely by the Advanced Installer guys: [**Advanced Installer: per-user setup limitations**](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/single-package.html).

---

[***WiX Issue 5481***](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/5481): I added an answer, but deleted it. It didn't work properly. I had a look in the **WiX Issues database** and this is a known issue: https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/5481. The last comment from **NicMay** looked interesting. I made a quick mock-up below incorporating his / her suggestions with some modifications.

***Disclaimer***: The below sample has a number of defects, and is only intended as a **`"runnable sample"`**. There are issues with MSI validation due to the shortcut quick-solution I used (use the shortcut to see where the file installed, right click and go **`"Properties"`**). The **`"Create New Folder"`** button in the custom installation dialog also has a bug. I will still post it to see if it helps you:

> ***NB!***: Create new WiX project, add reference to **`WixUIExtension.dll`**, then follow comments. Run setup and click **`"Advanced"`** to select per-user or per-machine install.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

<!--CHANGE #1: Add an UpgradeCode GUID below -->

  <Product Id="*" Name="PerUserOrPerMachine" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0"
           Manufacturer="Hobbit" UpgradeCode="PUT-GUID-HERE">    
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />
    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="PerUserOrPerMachine" Level="1" />      

<!--CHANGE #2: Here we channel "hacker" NicMay with his / her dialog event tweaks mentioned in the WiX issue 5481 -->

    <UI>
      <UIRef Id="WixUI_Advanced" />
      <Publish Dialog="InstallScopeDlg" Control="Next" Property="MSIINSTALLPERUSER" Value="1" Order="3">WixAppFolder = "WixPerUserFolder"</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="InstallScopeDlg" Control="Next" Property="MSIINSTALLPERUSER" Value="{}" Order="2">WixAppFolder = "WixPerMachineFolder"</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="InstallScopeDlg" Control="Next" Event="DoAction" Value="WixSetDefaultPerMachineFolder" Order="3">WixAppFolder = "WixPerMachineFolder"</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="InstallScopeDlg" Control="Next" Event="DoAction" Value="WixSetDefaultPerUserFolder" Order="3">WixAppFolder = "WixPerUserFolder"</Publish>
    </UI>

    <Property Id="ApplicationFolderName" Value="PerUserPerMachine" />
    <Property Id="WixAppFolder" Value="WixPerMachineFolder" />

<!--CHANGE #3: Add components and files as appropriate -->

    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">

<!--CHANGE #4: Make sure DesktopFolder is defined -->

      <Directory Id="DesktopFolder" />
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">

<!--CHANGE #5: Crucial: Make sure Directory Id is APPLICATIONFOLDER (referenced elsewhere) -->

        <Directory Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Name="PerUserOrPerMachine">
          <Component Feature="ProductFeature" Guid="{5A74A1EE-0AD3-4C48-9E6B-4E4E3712A8BB}">

<!--CHANGE #6: Hard coded path below for simplicity, change path or replace construct -->

            <File Source="D:\My Test Files\MyTestApplication.exe">
              <Shortcut Id="AppDesktopShortcut" Name="PerUserOrPerMachine" Directory="DesktopFolder"  />
            </File>

            <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\My Company\My Product" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes" />
          </Component>

        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>

  </Product>

</Wix>
```

---

***Links***:

- [WiX Simple Setup Per User Installer](https://github.com/deepak-rathi/Wix-Setup-Samples/tree/master/6.%20Wix%20Simple%20Setup%20Per%20User%20Installer) (sample per-user setup - should not install directly to user profile folders, but set install to ProgramFiles and then allow MSI to do folder redirection).

Comment: Don't get your hopes up too much, there are always unforeseen problems. Best of luck though. And keep in mind that per-user setups have many issues.

Comment: Oh, and [remember the list of limitations for per-user setups](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/single-package.html).

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks a lot :)  Ah yes, limitations.  Our client wants per user installs, so that's what we've got to do :/  We'll see if our current MSI breaks any of those limitations.

Comment: You must try that button in the browse for custom installation part dialog, it did not work properly (as I recall). You could just hide it and let people type in a path - perhaps? I am not sure. Should be possible to fix properly.

Comment: The only advanced UI we want is the choice between machine wide and per user installation.  I'm going to hide everything else, so we should be ok?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194386/discussion-between-stein-asmul-and-felix).