# Creating WiX MSI patch package or installing updates for non-admin users

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5, wix3.7

We are creating a MSI installer for a windows application using WiX (and DevOps pipeline), which asks users (non-admin) to enter admin credentials to install it and updates on their machine.

However, now our objective it to not to force them entering admin credentials while installing the updates.
After going through some (old) articles, I came to know it is possible using patching, however, have not got any concrete examples.
Highly appreciate if someone can guide or give pointers or if there is a better alternative to patching.

Comment: You can make MSI packages that install without admin rights. They need to be created in very specific ways and they are so called "per-user setups". [Generally I am not a fan of per-user setups](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52710390/129130). Maybe have a look at [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64335370/129130), or more specifically the WiX source markup at the bottom. You will see it installs with InstallScope="perUser" and InstallPrivilege="limited" as well as targeting a user profile folder.

Comment: Yes @SteinÅsmul. We want to let non-admin user to **only install updates**, **without requiring admin rights**, for already installed application. However, it should be installed first time only with admin rights.

Comment: You don't have a software distribution system such as SCCM or similar that will get this job done for you? I am not familiar with any method to install patches without admin rights. That would have to be patches that target user-profile locations only? There are logon scripts too. Group Policy assigned MSIs, scheduled tasks, etc...

Comment: No, we do not have any software distribution services. Right now, its implemented a very straightforward way (create installer, copy it on user machine and install the app). I am too not familiar with Wix so finding it a very stiff learning. I just read about patching somewhere so highly appreciate if you can provide some insights about the other alternatives. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @SteinÅsmul if I go for 'per-user' setups then It will not allow me to write registry keys without admin credentials, right?

Comment: That is correct, yes. There is a new packaging technology called [MSIX](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/msix-packaging.html) - maybe have a look. It deals with per-user setups more by design.

Comment: [Some ad-hoc information on technology development for deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49632260/129130). No claim to be totally up to date, but give it a quick skim?