# Installing a non-admin setup forced by Run as Administrator

Tags: windows, installation, wix, vsto, non-admin

I have created a **non-admin** installer using **Wix-tools**. Its working perfectly. But when I provide "**Run as Admin**" by right clicking the setup, it is installing in **ProgramFiles** Folder. But I need to install the setup in the user **LocalAppData** Folder even giving "Run as Admin". How can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: [Here is a sample in WiX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64335370/129130) - basically specify the installation directory to be in the user profile outright and not just be "re-targetable" from program files. There are a number of complications relating to per-user setups (patching, upgrades, etc...). Per machine installations are generally preferred.

Comment: [WiX quick start suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25005864/129130) (and other tips and links), and here are [some words about Visual Studio Installer projects limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47944893/129130) ([short version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2637666/129130)).